# Preventing CKEditor from removing classes assigned in source mode?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to be able to add a class attribute to a UL in source mode of CKEditor. When I do that and switch back to the normal editor mode the

```
 <ul class="xxxx">
```

becomes

```
 <ul>
```

How can I get it to not remove the class tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter.html).

You need to use [extraAllowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent) like this: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'ul(*)';` to allow any CSS class for `ul` element.

You can be more specific and allow only certain CSS classes, like this: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'ul(class1,class2,class3)';` (note no space between names).

You could also disable ACF (not ideal though) and allow everything like this: `config.allowedContent = true;`